# Implementation of ARM TrustZone on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, trustzone

It's my first time on Stack, be merciful please :D

I'm in Internship, and I work to run TrustZone on a Raspberry pi. I had already find some information on ARM documentation but it not really replied to my question. I tried to implement TrustZone with github.com/songwenbin247/TrustMe on github but I'm blocked on the 2.d. The commande line "file vexpress-a9.img" give me :vexpress-a9.img: x86 boot sector" but I haven't succeed to make partitions. Can someone tell me if it tutorial work to make TrustZone on Raspberry ? And what I must to do for make partitions ?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: this has been asked many times here and in the raspberry pi forums...

Comment: Surely ... :/ but all things I saw here didn't work ! Every time either it isn't compile or I don't know that I must do with files ...

Comment: provide specific examples of what you tried, what you expected and what it did instead of what you expected, be it compile time or runtime.

Comment: For example this one : https://github.com/songwenbin247/TrustMe

Comment: I failed to make 2.c : making the SD image

Comment: Not 2.c but it 2.d ... with "copy your kernel.img  to SD image". Which image they want ?

Comment: As @dwelch suggested, Update your question with the command lines you have tried and what "failed" means - did you get error message? What platform are you building your image on? More information will get your more help.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/blob/master/documentation/rpi3.md

The build will be improved further..

Btw, although the Pi3 implements the ARM V8a exception states the chip *is not secure*. A full implementation of TrustZone requires much more than exception states, which the Pi2 and Pi3 do not implement.